# Lift: Menu with multiple params [Menu.params]

Tags: scala, sitemap, lift

How to build an url with two or many params?

i've a case class:

```
case class PageDetail(index: String, id: String)
```

i'm trying to do a menu val:

```
val menu = Menu.params[(String,String)]( "pageDetail", "Page Detail",
    ids => { case Full(index) :: Full(id) :: Nil => Full((index, id))},
    pi => { case (index, id) => index :: id :: Nil }) / "admin" / "detail"
```

i would like to obtain a link as .../admin/detail/indexxxxxxx/idddddddddd where indexxxxxxx and idddddddddd are my params.
as is doesn't work. Error in compile time. How can i do?
Thanks

Comment: Not enough information: what does the "compile-time error" say? Did you read it?

Comment: The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
[error] Expected type was: net.liftweb.common.Box[(String, String)]
[error]     ids => { case Full(index) :: Full(id) :: Nil => Full((index, id))},
[error]            ^
[error] (brainaetic-web/compile:compile) Compilation failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the issue is in your extractor pattern. When you are matching on your list here:

```
case Full(index) :: Full(id) :: Nil => Full((index, id))
```

The parameters are always going to be defined, so the `Full` is not possible. You can use functions, such as [`AsInt`](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/#net.liftweb.util.BasicTypesHelpers) to require the parameter to be an Int, or else it will look for a String. You'd most likely want to start with the following (Or some variation on that):

```
case index :: id :: Nil => Full((index, id))
```

If you are using Empty to mean the parameter is optional, then you would simply add a second `case` statement after it with the parameter omitted.

Also, you probably need to add `/ **` to the end of you `/ "admin" / "detail"` mapping so it knows to grab the parameters from there.

So, the code should look something like this:

```
val menu = Menu.params[(String,String)]( "pageDetail", "Page Detail",
  { 
    case index :: id :: Nil => Full((index, id))
  }, { 
    case (index, id) => index :: id :: Nil 
  }
) / "admin" / "detail" / **
```

Comment: Hi @jcern. I've updated the code with your suggestions but i've the same error: Type mismatch, expected: ((String, String)) => List(String), actual: ((String, String)) => Any

Comment: @YoBre, I updated the answer with the suggested codeblock. Those changes should let the code work for you.